# Finding the shortest rotation between Quaternions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, difference, quaternions

My Problem:

I'm trying to align Gameobject A with GameObject B's rotation, although the important detail is that GoA can either align 1:1 with GoB's rotation, or the inverse of GoB's rotation (ie. a hand picking up a pencil with tip side up, or the opposite and tip side down).

What I'm trying to do is find which option (1:1 or inverse) is the closest rotation, so would it be the shortest route to rotate to.

Example:

[Scenario A and B where the red line represents GoA, and the black line represents GoB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwbI4.png)

In the example above, scenario A the red line (GoA) should find the closest rotation as 1:1 with the black line (GoB), whereas in scenario B the red line should find the closest rotation as the inverse to the black line.

This solution would need to work in 3D space, and avoid gimble lock.

Thanks very much for any help, if more info is required, I'll edit it onto this original post!

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Do quaternion dot product with each potential rotation.  Smallest result is closer.  Then, the way to rotate to the closer rotation is by using quaternion slerp.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "closer".

Suppose the the target is in a room with a door and windows across from it.

The target is upright and looking at the door, and the inverse target is looking at the windows but is upside-down.

The subject is looking between the door and windows, only just a little closer to the windows, and is upright.

Which candidate is "closer" for your needs?

---

If you consider the target here to be "closer" because the subject is already upright, and you care about the entire rotation difference between subject and target, you can use `Quaternion.Angle` to determine which one has a smaller difference from the identity rotation:

```
Transform target;
Transform subject;

Quaternion subjectRot = subject.rotation;
Quaternion targetRot = target.rotation;

// however you define "inverse" here
Qutaternion invTargetRot = targetRot * Quaternion.Euler(180f,0f,0f);

float angleToTarget = Quaternion.Angle(subjectRot, targetRot);
float angleToInvTarget = Quaternion.Angle(subjectRot, invTargetRot);

if (angleToTarget <= angleToInvTarget) 
{
    // alignment with target is closer
}
else 
{
    // alignment with inverse of target is closer
}
```

---

If you consider the inverse target here to be "closer" because you only care about one local direction of subject/target (e.g., forward) and don't care about the others (e.g., up/right), then you can just use `Vector3.Angle` to compare the directions, and if the angle is less than 90 degrees, it's closer to align:

```
Transform target;
Transform subject;

// or *.up, or *.right depending on your needs
float angleToTarget = Vector3.Angle(subject.forward, target.forward);

if (angleToTarget <= 90f) 
{
    // alignment with target is closer
}
else 
{
    // alignment with inverse of target is closer
}
```